# How can I customize Adobe Creative SDK Image for Android?

Tags: android, adobe, aviary

The Adobe Creative SDK Image Editing says that developers can customize the UI by editing xml files, but I don't see any xml files in the sdk directory. I asked for more documentation to Adobe, but haven't got any feedback. Please help.

https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html

9. Customization
   You can customize almost all the visual aspects of the CreativeSDKImage UI by editing the style entries in the aviary_styles.xml, aviary_colors.xml, aviary_dimens.xml and aviary_config.xml files.
   Most of the custom attributes you'll find inside the aviary_theme.xml and aviary_styles.xml files are documented inside the aviary_attrs.xml file.
   The aviary_config.xml file contains all the customizable behaviors of the SDK like the colors to show inside the text tool or the drawing tool, the sizes of the brush tools, the custom crop ratios for the crop tool, the default font used in the meme tool, etc..
   Inside the aviary_config.xml file you'll find a detailed description of every entry.

Comment: If you found anything helpful then please post.

Comment: https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/attachments/token/zGLSRHRGpKriRWhYzQ0dR9pUt/?name=android-customization-docs.zip

This is what I've got from Adobe Creative SDK support team but I couldn't make it work. When I try to build my project, it gives me "Error:(1) Attribute "------------" has already been defined". I just gave up :(

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm little late to answer you but this can be helpful to others.
As I work with Creative SDK, I just learned how to customize UI of the Aviary Editor.

> By overriding xml files, you can make changes in Aviary Editor's UI.

[Click on this link to find detailed explanation...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581005/how-to-remove-creative-cloud-reference-or-footer-from-aviary-editor/32692444#32692444)