# How to remove Footer from Aviary Editor?

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I'm working on an simple image editor. Aviary's Signup for Aviary Image Editor SDK is disable and it is now coming with Adobe's Creative Sdk. No doubt they are providing so much features, But they are not useful for my simple image editor.

I just want to use some image editing tools like crop and orientation. So I have written the below code in my MainActivity.

```
    String[] tools = new String[] { "CROP", "ORIENTATION" };        
    Intent newIntent = new AviaryIntent.Builder(this)
            .setData(imageUri)                            // input image src
            .withOutput(Uri.parse("file://" + "abc.jpg")) // output file
            .withOutputFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG) // output format
            .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp5)               // output size
            .withOutputQuality(90)                        // output quality
            .build();
    newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_TOOLS_LIST, tools);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);
```

The problem is, I want to remove `Creative Cloud Connected` link in the footer of the editor.
Please provide some solution.

> Note: It is just a demo app for learning purpose, not for production.
>   We are not going to release it anywhere.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have worked with Creative SDK, I just learned how to customize UI of the Aviary Editor.

> By overriding xml files, you can make changes in Aviary Editor's UI.

I have a simple example below, I made some changes in editor's footer. I just created new xml file `aviary_bottombar.xml` in app module as following...

[image: Overridden xml file in app module]

You can find the original implementation in `exploaded-aar` directory of sdk as shown below...

[image: Exploded Aar files of creative sdk]

Hope it will help somebody...

Comment: is that ok to remove creative Creative Cloud Connected link from editor, Is branding option to use editor?

Comment: It is just an example, you can add whatever you want.

Comment: yes it is, but we have to approve app from adobe before going to production. I don't thing adobe will allow us to use Creative SDK without any branding logo.

Comment: have you submitted app for review to adobe?

Comment: Okay I understand, I will contact to them. And sorry

Comment: I am just curious, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Really Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically feasible to pull this off, it is against the Creative SDK Terms of Use to remove the Creative Cloud badge from the Image Editor. Apps that violate the Terms of Use will not be approved for production.

[You can find the Adobe Creative SDK terms here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/legal/servicetou/Creative_SDK-en_US.pdf).

[The Adobe general terms are here](http://www.adobe.com/misc/terms.html).

Comment: Thanks for the details, but it was only a demo app. We did not publish it anywhere.